# How to achieve a loop extra-condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to realize something very simple but can't find the right solution: how to replace signs in a string if founded in a scope and keep them 'as is' if not.

```
    var BASE = "ABCDEFGHIJ"; 
    var CODE = "0123456789";
    var WORD = "DEKF" // K is out of range
    var CONS = []; // result expected: 34K5

    for (b=0; b<BASE.length; b++){

        for (w=0; w<WORD.length; w++){

            // if a sign of WORD is in BASE we change it with CODE equivalent: A->0
            if(WORD[w]==BASE[b]) {
                CONS.push(CODE[b]); 
            }

            // if not we keep it in place 
            else {
                // make sure the sign is out of BASE range
                if(BASE.search(WORD[w]) == -1 ) { 
                    CONS.push(WORD[w]); 
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
    }

    console.log(CONS.join(''))
```

CONSOLE

```
without the else condition = 345 ( no K )
else cond without break = KKK3K4KK5KKKK
else cond with break = KKK3K4KKKKKK
else without if->match and without break = DEKFDEKFDEKF3EKFD4KFDEK5DEKFDEKFDEKFDEKF
else without if->match and with break = DDD3EDDDDDD
with continue instead of break =  KKK3K4KK5KKKK
```

Then I've tried with a label to break the loop:

```
    for (b=0; b<BASE.length; b++){

        sign:
        for (w=0; w<WORD.length; w++){

            // if a sign of WORD is in BASE we change it with CODE equivalent: A -> 0
            if(WORD[w]==BASE[b]) {
                CONS.push(CODE[b]); 
            }

            // if not we keep it in place: 
            else {
                if(BASE.search(WORD[w]) == -1 ) { // make sure the sign is out of BASE range
                    CONS.push(WORD[w]); 
                    break sign;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

CONSOLE

```
with sign label and break sign = KKK3K4KKKKKK
with sign label before the first loop and break sign; = K
```

Answer (score 2):

To provide an alternative. Especially if the list gets longer and for maintainability you can use a `Map` instead of 2 loose strings.
(In the example below the Map has been created from the strings)

After that you can simply replace all characters with either the entry of the map or the character itself:

```js
const BASE = "ABCDEFGHIJ", CODE = "0123456789", WORD = "DEKF",
 codes = new Map([...BASE].map((b,i)=> [b,CODE[i]]));
    
let CONS = [...WORD].map(s=> codes.get(s) || s);

console.log(CONS.join(''));
```

Comment: tried with an extra long BASE ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ÀÂÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÖÔÙÛÜàâäçéèêëîïôöùûü#@'?_-.,$! -> works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the outer loop to iterate your WORD variable and the inner loop
Should iterate the BASE, this way you only iterate once for each letter in WORD

Working Fiddle:
(https://jsfiddle.net/3csxu8L6/1/)

```js
var BASE = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
var CODE = "0123456789";
var WORD = "DEKF" // K is out of range
var CONS = []; // result expected: 34K5



for (w = 0; w < WORD.length; w++) {
  for (b = 0; b < BASE.length; b++) {

    // if a sign of WORD is in BASE we change it with CODE equivalent: A->0
    if (WORD[w] == BASE[b]) {
      CONS.push(CODE[b]);
    }

    // if not we keep it in place 
    else {
      // make sure the sign is out of BASE range
      if (BASE.search(WORD[w]) == -1) {
        CONS.push(WORD[w]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

alert(CONS.join(''));
```

Comment: @Wolden Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```js
var BASE = "ABCDEFGHIJ"; 
var CODE = "0123456789";
var WORD = "DEKF" // K is out of range
var CONS = []; // result expected: 34K5

Array.from(WORD).forEach(l => {

  let index = BASE.length
  let found = false
  
  while(--index >= 0) {
    if(BASE[index] === l) {
      CONS.push(index);
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    CONS.push(l)
  }
  
} )

console.log(CONS) // [3,4,K,5]
```

This is also one of the VERY fast solutions possible.

Comment: Shouldn't your while loop be `while(--index >= 0)` or else you skip the first character in `BASE`

Comment: @RyanWilson Oops, fixed it. Thanks!